# Why does C++ lambda overloading not behave as expected?

Tags: c++, lambda, overloading, standards, c++20

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename... Args_>
concept IsCallable = std::is_invocable_v<T, Args_...>;

struct A
{
    int n = 0;

    void f(IsCallable<int&> auto const fn)
    {
        fn(n);
    }

    void f(IsCallable<int const&> auto const fn) const
    {
        fn(n);
    }
};

struct Lambda
{
    void operator()(auto& n) const
    {
        n = 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto a = A{};
    a.f(Lambda{});               // ok
    a.f([](auto& n) { n = 1; }); // error: assignment of read-only reference 'n'
}
```

See [online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ocMnbMW8z)

**Why does C++ lambda overloading not behave as expected?**

Comment: It seems that for some reason the overload resolution wants it to be the `const` function and `auto&` is deduced to `int const&` despite the change of value. Changing it to `int&` fixes it, but weird nevertheless, especially as above line works. With concepts this can be avoided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your question is nearly a duplicate of [Hard error when using std::invoke_result_t with a generic lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53344484/hard-error-when-using-stdinvoke-result-t-with-a-generic-lambda) . As with the other question, your code will work the way you expect, if you change the lambda so that it has an explicit `-> void` return type, thus avoiding return type deduction.
2. The difference between your question and the other one is that in your question, you're using `std::invocable_v` rather than `std::invoke_result_t`. However, the code in this case is still ill-formed because return type deduction is still triggered even though you're not asking for it.
3. The standard requires `is_invocable` to determine whether or not the *INVOKE* expression would be "well-formed when treated as an unevaluated operand". libstdc++ and libc++ both use `decltype` to create an unevaluated operand for this purpose, so, obviously, return type deduction has to be done. But it seems to me that [there is no way to avoid triggering return type deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64913154/why-return-type-deduction-can-not-support-sfinae-with-stdis-invocable-v), therefore there is no possible standard library implementation that would allow your code to compile (it is not a bug in GCC/Clang).